# ag-grid Filter menu appears behind the rendered cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ag-grid

**Background**

I am using `headerComponent` and `cellRenderer` in my grid as well as *infinite scrolling*.

I now wanted to use filtering and maybe sorting and I followed the instructions in the documentation.

**Problem**

The icons/buttons for the filter and the sort do not appear.

I thought it might be related to the Renderers and this seems to be the case. I tried not using the `headerComponent` and then I could see the filter and sort icons in the header. But then the menu which opened was behind the cells in the table. The cells are still handled by their `cellRenderer`. I tried messing with the `z-index` but I did not manage to bring that menu to the front.

Is there something I should know about this? I did some searches but did not find anything useful on the topic. I can avoid using the Renderer for the headers but I cannot avoid them in the cells.

**Related question?**

On a maybe related topic, I do not manage to show the overlays at all. Maybe these too are actually hidden behind the cells?